# Splitting NSString into two parts (before and after last slash)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Is there a better (more concise/efficient/elegant) way than this for splitting a string that contains a slash into two parts: one before, the other after the last slash.

```
NSRange range = [s rangeOfString: @"/" options: NSBackwardsSearch];
NSAssert(range.location != NSNotFound, nil);

NSString *s1 = [s substringToIndex: range.location];
NSString *s2 = [s substringFromIndex: range.location + 1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use 
- componentsSeparatedByString:

eg

```
NSArray *components = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

NSString *s1 = ((![components count])? nil :[components objectAtIndex:0] );
NSString *s2 = ((![components count]>0)? nil :[components objectAtIndex:1] );
```

Comment: Do you want to complete this with index calcuation re last slash, then I'll accept. (`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` may be even more appropriate.)

Comment: I don't think these indices are correct for *last* slash, but thx anyway.